# Minimum circle encompassing multiple bounding boxes

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a set of bounding boxes (lower/upper x,y) in 2D. I would like to find the diameter of the smallest circle that encompasses these bounding boxes.

I am not too familiar with computational geometry algorithms, but a Google search turned up these links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere or this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem

Questions:

1. Is the problem specified above the same as the links mentioned above (but in 2D)? If so, I can apply/implement the Ritter algorithm or maybe the Minball solution https://github.com/hbf/miniball?
2. Is there an existing python package/function (maybe Shapely?) that does this already?

Answer (score 0):

Minimum circle is always defined by vertices of the polygons, not by edges.

So you can apply any smallest circle algorithm to the set of box vertices (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right).

*(there might be a lot of inner vertices, but preliminary removing of apparent inner points does not seem simpler than circle algo)*